# average of duplicate data from one table in mysql

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, average

I have a table like this:

```
+----+---------------------+----------+
| ID | startDate           | uvIndex  | 
+----+---------------------+----------+
|  1 | 2014-10-29 06:37:21 | 120      | 
|  2 | 2014-10-29 08:57:00 | 135      | 
|  3 | 2014-10-28 05:37:21 | 120      |  
|  4 | 2014-10-28 09:30:21 | 160      |  
|  5 | 2014-10-28 10:28:21 | 150      |  
|  6 | 2014-10-26 16:27:01 | 150      |  
|  7 | 2014-10-26 17:57:21 | 110      | 
+----+----------+-----+---------------+
```

From there I want distinct values but if data is repetitive then the average of that data should come. Like this:

```
+----+-------------+---------------+
| ID | startDate   | AVG(uvIndex)  | 
+----+-------------+---------------+
|  1 | 2014-10-29  | 127.5         | 
|  2 | 2014-10-28  | 98.33         | 
|  3 | 2014-10-26  | 130           |  
+----+----------+-----+------------+
```

My attempt so far :

```
SELECT AVG(accumulatedLux), startTime FROM `blutooth_accumulated_data` WHERE `startTime` BETWEEN '2014-10-25' AND '2014-10-30' GROUP BY startTime
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, your query should produce the data you want.  The only issue is the `id`, which you can get using a variable.  Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT (@id := @id + 1) as id, startTime, AVG(accumulatedLux)
FROM `blutooth_accumulated_data` CROSS JOIN
      (SELECT @id := 0) vars
WHERE `startTime` BETWEEN '2014-10-25' AND '2014-10-30'
GROUP BY startTime
ORDER BY startTime;
```

One possible complication is if the `StartTime` has a *time* component.  If so, you want this:

```
SELECT (@id := @id + 1) as id, date(startTime) as startDate, AVG(accumulatedLux)
FROM `blutooth_accumulated_data` CROSS JOIN
      (SELECT @id := 0) vars
WHERE date(startTime) BETWEEN '2014-10-25' AND '2014-10-30'
GROUP BY date(startTime)
ORDER BY date(startTime);
```

And a small note.  So you can use an index on `startTime`, you should write the `where` clause as:

```
WHERE startTime >= date('2014-10-15') and startTime < date('2014-10-30') + interval 1 day
```

Comment: Yes I have time components.

Comment: ``ORDER BY expr`` is redundant when you group by the same expression.

Comment: with the help of date component I also got the same result. `SELECT AVG(accumulatedLux), date(startTime) FROM blutooth_accumulated_data WHERE date(startTime) BETWEEN '2014-10-25' AND '2014-11-30' GROUP BY date(startTime)`